# Mobile keyboard up and down on button click

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile

We have developed a small chat app for mobile. In footer we have a text field and button to send message.

When we click on the button the keyboard has been toggles(down and up) here. Because when we click on the button, it unfocus the input field then keyboard downs. Then we forcefully clearing the message and again we are focusing the cursor to input field, here keyboard opens.

Its very annoying. But it is not happening in whats app and facebook apps.

Can anybody suggest how we can achieve this. We are using jquery mobile ui js.

Thanks,
Govind.

Answer (score 0):

One way to close a virtual keyboard it to move the focus to another input, then blur it immediately. Try this on a click event for your button.

```
$('#someinput').focus().blur();
```

Answer (score 0):

i tried this and it works:

```
$('#someinput').focus(function(){
  //do what ever you want

  $(this).blur() 
  //this will turn off the focus from the input and automaticlly should slide down the keyboard.
})
```